# How to convert a each column of a cell array to an array in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array C looks like:

```
   start        end
  -------      --------
     a           b
     c           d
     d           a
```

I need to generate two arrays s=[a,c,d] and t=[b,d,a] from C.

Can you tell me how I can do it in Matlab?

Comment: That looks like a `table` rather than a `cell`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a cell array you can simply grab each column and convert to an array using `cellmat`

```
A = cellmat(C(:,1));
B = cellmat(C(:,2));
```

If the contents of each cell element is non-scalar, you'll need to leave them as a `cell`, so you'll want to simply use `()` indexing

```
A = C(:,1);
B = C(:,2);
```

However, it looks like you actually have a `table` in which case you can reference the columns directly

```
A = C.start;
B = C.end;
```